# jQuery replaceWith deleting my :after pseudoelement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element

I have some code which uses the jQuery `replaceWith` function, but it seems `replaceWith` gets rid of the pseudoelement `:after` on the div I'm invoking `replaceWith` on.

Is there a similar function that acts exactly the same as `replaceWith` but does not destroy my `:after` pseudoelement?

Here's my code:

```
$("#someDiv").replaceWith("some text here");
```

Is this intended behavior of jQuery or is it a bug?

Comment: Of course if you replace to `div` targeted by the CSS, it will remove the styles... What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's the intended behavior of CSS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.replaceWith` removes the element it's called on. And a `:after` pseudo-element cannot exist without its element.

You can use `$("#someDiv").html("some text here");` to replace the div **content**, not the div itself

Answer (score 2):

it does not destroy the `:after`. what happens is that when you delete div, `div:after` can't be displayed as there is no element it should be displayed after.